# Can I achieve the following with javascript or jquery? I have multiple buttons that, on click, I would like to reveal a div but close the previous

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few buttons in a section that I would like to click and have each one reveal their respective DIV ID (essentially a section of three blogs specific to that button that's pushed), but the thing I can't figure out is this....

How, when clicked can I click another button to reveal the respective div but close the other one I clicked before it?

I tried the following:

```
<script> function toggle(e){
    const button = e.target;
    const divId = button.dataset.targetId;
    const div = document.getElementById(divId);

    if(div.classList.contains("hidden")){
        div.classList.remove("hidden");
        div.classList.add("show")
    }
    else{
        div.classList.remove("show");
        div.classList.add("hidden")
    }
}
</script>
```

I attached a hidden class to all div sections I need to reveal when a button is clicked.

i.e. one of my buttons has this as the code:

`<button data-target-id="Toilet-Repair-Articles" onclick="toggle(event)" class="white-transparent-button-white-rollover">Toilet is Running</button>`

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this example?

(See comments in the code for some clarifications.)

```js
const containerDiv = document.querySelector("#container-div");
containerDiv.addEventListener('click', showRow); // Uses event delegation

function showRow(event){
  const clicked = event.target;
  if(clicked.tagName != 'BUTTON'){ return; } // Ignores irrelevant clicks

  for(row of containerDiv.children){
    const display = row.querySelector(".display");
    if(row == clicked.parentElement){
      display.classList.remove("hidden"); // Shows only corresponding display
    }
    else{
      display.classList.add("hidden");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* CSS rules other than `.hidden` are just for this demo  */
#container-div{ margin: 1em; }
.row{ width: 10em; height: 1.4em; margin-bottom: 1em; padding: 0.2em; border: 1px solid lightgrey; }
.display{ display: inline-block; }
button{ float: right; }

.hidden{ display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="container-div">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="display">AAAAA</div>
        <button>SHOW</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="display hidden">BBBBB</div>
        <button>SHOW</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="display hidden">CCCCC</div>
        <button>SHOW</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="display hidden">DDDDD</div>
        <button>SHOW</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this, but to no avail unfortunately. The buttons are in the same div id container but they aren't contained in the div that the action is happening if that makes sense? I can provide a link to the website I'm currently doing and if you go down the page you'll see a section with buttons that reads "Need Help?" and the buttons below should get clicked and reveal a pop down section of three blog posts for a category. [link](https://plumbers911dev.wpengine.com/)

Comment: Also....note that you'll see if you pop open the code there is a "hidden" class for three of these rows that are currently hidden on the page.

Comment: That's expected in different HTML. Instead of the simple `clicked.parentElement` expression from the example, you'll want to select any ancestor element by using the [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method -- which works just like [Element.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) but going up the DOM tree instead of down. (And if your target div isn't actually a direct ancestor, you'd just use `Element.querySelector()` to select your target div from the shared ancestor you got with `.closest()`.)

Comment: Sorry, but am I just replacing clicked.parentElement with Element.closest()?

Comment: If your target div is a direct ancestor of your button, then yes. However `.closest` takes one argument, a css-type selector, so it knows which ancestor element to go to. In the example above, for instance, you could use `.closest(".row")` to find the closest ancestor with the row class.